# Prove the equality of the determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A be square matrix with dimesions of: $3\leqslant n$, prove the equality of the determinants.

$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & n & n & \cdots & n \\
n & 2 & n & \cdots & n \\
n & n & 3 & \cdots  & n \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &  \ddots  & \vdots \\
n & n & n & \cdots  & n \\
\end{vmatrix} = (-1)^{n+1}n!$

**My solution so far is:**

I subtracted the last row from all other rows: $\begin{vmatrix}
1 - n & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 2-n & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3-n & \cdots  & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &  \ddots  & \vdots \\
n & n & n & \cdots  & n \\
\end{vmatrix} $

I took common divisor from each line:
$(1-n)*(2-n)*(3-n)*...*n*\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &  \ddots  & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots  & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

Then I subtracted all the rows from the last row: $(1-n)*(2-n)*(3-n)*...*n*\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & n \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & n \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  &  \ddots  & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
 $

And so the determinant I got is: $det(A) = (1-n)*(2-n)*(3-n)*...*n \neq (-1)^{n+1}n!$
I would like to get your help to find my mistake

Comment: $n \cdot \prod\limits_{i = 1}^{n-1} (i-n) = n \cdot (-1)^{n-1} \prod\limits_{I = 1}^{n-1} (n-i) = (-1)^{n-1} \cdot n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=1$, your method doesn't work because its first step makes no sense. Otherwise, it is correct. Note that $k-n=-(n-k)$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. Therefore, what you got is equal to$$(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\cdots\times1\times n=(-1)^{n-1}n!=(-1)^{n+1}n!$$